# Use merge field for Recipient fields

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I know when you create a Signer, and use the *EmbeddedRecipientStartURL* property, you can include merge fields in the URL like http://sitehost/[[recipientEmail]]/.

Is there anyway to assign merge field values to other recipient properties, like *clientUserId*? I would like to do something like *clientUserId = [[recipientEmail]]*. I need to do this because the signer's (recipient's) email will be set in the createSender view:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
```

Code for Signer

```
    Signer s1 = new Signer
    {
        ClientUserId = [[recipientEmail]],
        RecipientId = "1",
        RoleName = "role",
        EmbeddedRecipientStartURL = "https://redirectUrl/[[envelopeId]]/[[recipientId]]"
    };
```